# Click action on ActionBar$Tab

Tags: java, android, appium-android

I am writing test scripts for android using appium.
How do i perform click actions on ActionBar$Tab elements?Is there anyway i can pass the xpaths with $ using escape characters?How can i get appium to click on tab elements?

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath with the text inside it. It's actually Actionbar.tab class which gets converted to ActionBar$Tab which fails when you use in script. Try using  xpath with android textview and it's position in the hierarchy like ("(//android.widget.textview).instance(3)"). Or use driver.findelementbyAndroidUiautomator("text(\"sample\")");